# wget gives 403 on accessible files

Tags: anaconda, conda, wget

First time poster with a bizarre issue I am having. I usually install software through conda, but from one moment to the other I stopped being able to use `conda install` because of a 403 I get from conda trying to access some configuration files. When trying to download those files with `wget --spider --debug https://conda.anaconda.org/anaconda/noarch/current_repodata.json`, I get the same 403 error.

```
DEBUG output created by Wget 1.19.4 on linux-gnu.

Reading HSTS entries from /home/jsequeira/.wget-hsts
URI encoding = ‘UTF-8’
Converted file name 'current_repodata.json' (UTF-8) -> 'current_repodata.json' (UTF-8)
Spider mode enabled. Check if remote file exists.
--2020-07-30 11:25:59--  https://conda.anaconda.org/anaconda/noarch/current_repodata.json
Resolving conda.anaconda.org (conda.anaconda.org)... 104.17.92.24, 104.17.93.24, 2606:4700::6811:5d18, ...
Caching conda.anaconda.org => 104.17.92.24 104.17.93.24 2606:4700::6811:5d18 2606:4700::6811:5c18
Connecting to conda.anaconda.org (conda.anaconda.org)|104.17.92.24|:443... connected.
Created socket 5.
Releasing 0x000056545deb1850 (new refcount 1).
Initiating SSL handshake.
Handshake successful; connected socket 5 to SSL handle 0x000056545deb2700
certificate:
  subject: CN=anaconda.org,O=Cloudflare\\, Inc.,L=San Francisco,ST=CA,C=US
  issuer:  CN=Cloudflare Inc ECC CA-3,O=Cloudflare\\, Inc.,C=US
X509 certificate successfully verified and matches host conda.anaconda.org

---request begin---
HEAD /anaconda/noarch/current_repodata.json HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Wget/1.19.4 (linux-gnu)
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: identity
Host: conda.anaconda.org
Connection: Keep-Alive

---request end---
HTTP request sent, awaiting response...
---response begin---
HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
Date: Thu, 30 Jul 2020 11:25:59 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Connection: close
CF-Chl-Bypass: 1
Set-Cookie: __cfduid=d3cd3a67d3926551371d8ffe5a840b04f1596108359; expires=Sat, 29-Aug-20 11:25:59 GMT; path=/; domain=.anaconda.org; HttpOnly; SameSite=Lax
Cache-Control: private, max-age=0, no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
cf-request-id: 044111dd9600005d4732b73200000001
Expect-CT: max-age=604800, report-uri="https://report-uri.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/beacon/expect-ct"
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Server: cloudflare
CF-RAY: 5baeb8dc2ba65d47-LIS

---response end---
403 Forbidden
cdm: 1

Stored cookie anaconda.org -1 (ANY) / <permanent> <insecure> [expiry 2020-08-29 11:25:59] __cfduid d3cd3a67d3926551371d8ffe5a840b04f1596108359
URI content encoding = ‘UTF-8’
Closed 5/SSL 0x000056545deb2700
Remote file does not exist -- broken link!!!
```

These files are accessible through the browser, and were always accessible with wget and conda until yesterday, when I was installing some tools not related to these network accesses. How can wget fail to download them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this was fixed by reinstalling apt-get. Some configuration file there must have been messed up.